# Execute SQL from cursor value

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, dynamic-sql, toad

(Just to preempt - I know how hacky and flawed this approach is. It's just going to be a personal use thing to make a certain task easier.)

For this example, I want to create two dynamic SQL insert statements which insert the first two results from ALL_TABLES into GT_DUMMY, padded with an input value.

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE GT_DUMMY
  ( Test_Field VARCHAR(100)
  );

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOAD_GT_DUMMY
  ( Insert_String VARCHAR
  )   
  IS      
  BEGIN

  FOR col IN
    ( SELECT 'INSERT INTO GT_DUMMY VALUES(' || CHR(39) || Insert_String || Table_Name || CHR(39) || ');' AS insertStatement
        FROM ALL_TABLES
       WHERE ROWNUM <= 2
    ) LOOP

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(col.insertStatement);
    -- Result of EXEC LOAD_GT_DUMMY('SOMETHING'); :
    --     INSERT INTO GT_DUMMY VALUES('SOMETHINGDUAL');
    --     INSERT INTO GT_DUMMY VALUES('SOMETHINGSYSTEM_PRIVILEGE_MAP');

    -- This command fails when 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE col.insertStatement;

    END LOOP;

END;
```

The inserts are well formed and will execute if I just run them standalone, but the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE col.insertStatement; command is not working. The procedure compiles, but when I try to run

```
EXEC LOAD_GT_DUMMY('SOMETHING');
```

I get an error

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at "MY_SCHEMA.LOAD_GT_DUMMY", line 14
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Any thoughts? Is my syntax off?

Best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the terminating semi-colon; dynamic SQL doesn't like it.

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO GT_DUMMY VALU... <snip> ... || CHR(39) || ');' 
                                                                ^
                                                                |
                                                               here
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `INTO v_result` in the end of `EXECUTE` statement

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE col.insertStatement INTO v_result;`

P.S. don't forget to declare `v_result` variable

You can check similar example down [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the colon in sql statement and execute it will work

```
FOR col IN
  ( SELECT 'INSERT INTO GT_DUMMY VALUES(' || CHR(39) || Insert_String || Table_Name || CHR(39) || ')' AS insertStatement
      FROM ALL_TABLES
     WHERE ROWNUM <= 2
  ) LOOP
```